# $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-c}{g(x)}$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

My question involves evaluating the limit of the function:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-c}{g(x)}$

Where:

$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$,
$\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0$, $f,g \in C^{1}$
and $c \in \mathbb{R}$

It seems I could just do:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{c}{g(x)}$

I can apply L'Hospitals to the first one, and assuming f and g are nice enough, get a nice answer, but the second one gives me $\infty$ so the whole limit must be $\infty$ as well.

However, intuitively, it doesn't seem like the constant $c$ should matter that much, and I should be apply to apply L'Hospitals without first breaking up the fraction since $c^{'} = 0$ anyway. However, the strict statements of the theorems won't allow this because $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) - c = c \neq 0$.

So, which/what is the correct way to evaluate this limit?

Comment: BTW,I am assuming g can't be made any simpler. For instance, if g just a linear function of x.

Comment: Why do you think $c$ doesn't matter much? Consider $x/x$ and $(x-1)/x$.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on $c$.

If $c\neq 0$, this is unbounded as $x$ approaches $0$. It can tend to $+\infty$, $-\infty$, or it can have no limit. For an example of each of these situations, take $c=1$, $f(x)=x$ and then $g(x)=x^2$, or $g(x)=-x^2$, or $g(x)=x$. And even wilder: $g(x)=\sin x$.

If $c=0$, you can now apply l'Hospital.

Answer (score 0):

When $c\neq 0$, you get $\frac{c}{0}$ which of course does not converge.

When $c=0$, you can do something like L'H rule

Just note that only when the limit is $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ that L'H rule is applicable.